# ViewControllers Navigation

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiviewcontroller

I have one base view controller "contentViewController" with one button
the action on button is

```
(IBAction) goBack:(id)sender
```

**.h file**

```
@interface ContentView : UIViewController {
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) UIViewController *display;


-(IBAction) goBack:(id) sender;
```

**.m file**

```
@synthesize display;

-(IBAction) goBack:(id)sender{
    UIViewController *view= display;
    [display release];
    [self presentModalViewController:view animated:YES];
}
```

and there are some other view controllers already exist each view controller contain on button to show content on the contentViewController.. here is one class example:

**.h file**

```
@interface Info : UIViewController {

}

-(IBAction) viewHealthInfoContent:(id) sender;
```

**.m file**

```
-(IBAction) viewHealthInfoContent:(id)sender{
    ContentView *cv=[ContentView alloc];
    [cv setDisplay:self];
    [self presentModalViewController:cv animated:YES];
    [cv release];
}
```

the case is, each time i show content from one view controller i need to go back to it. using that one goBack button on the contentViewController but when i click the go back button it doesn't do any think !!! any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to go back your previous viewController, use dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:: method.

According [source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) :

```
Dismisses the modal view controller that was presented by the receiver.
```

> In iOS, you can display views modally by presenting the controller for the modal view from your current view controller. When you present a view modally using the presentModalViewController:animated: method, the view controller animates the appearance of the view using the technique you specify. (You can specify the desired technique by setting the modalTransitionStyle property.) At the same time, the method creates a parent-child relationship between the current view controller and the modal view controller.

[Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: thank you so much jonathan for the fast reply you really helped me